NVIDIA cufft Memory free-up
When I loop through the following code, the GPU memory continues to increase
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cufft.h>

#define CHECK_CUFFT_ERROR(call) {                                     \
    cufftResult err = call;                                           \
    if (err != CUFFT_SUCCESS) {                                       \
        std::cerr << "CUFFT error: " << err << std::endl;             \
        exit(1);                                                      \
    }                                                                 \
}


int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        int width = 512;
        int height = 512;
        cufftHandle planR2C, planC2R;
        cufftPlan2d(&planR2C, height, width, CUFFT_R2C);
        cufftPlan2d(&planC2R, height, width, CUFFT_C2R);
        CHECK_CUFFT_ERROR(cufftDestroy(planR2C));
        CHECK_CUFFT_ERROR(cufftDestroy(planC2R));
    }

}

GPU memory usage does not increase with the number of cycles and shows an upward trend
